# How to make Eclipse CDT recognize "emit" keyword?

Tags: qt, macros, eclipse-cdt, qt-signals

[image: can't recognize "emit"]

As you can see, within Eclipse CDT, the Qt keyword `emit` is always being treated as an unresolved type.

How do I enable Eclipse CDT to resolve Qt macros such as "emit"?